# How can I get data in rows and columns order

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains 8 rows 
Like 
1001
1002
1003
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
1008 
From these I want to display the records as 4 columns *2 rows

```
1001 1002 1003 1004

1005 1006 1007 1008
```

How can I get this? 
Kindly assist me

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER with moduls, if there is a reminder after dividing with four increment a variable,group by that variable. As to GROUP_CONCAT in sql server its a pretty common question

Comment: Tables != Spreadsheets. You're starting down a dark path here. Better to do *presentation* logic like this up in the *presentation* layer, not deep down in the database.

Answer (score 0):

For your exact problem, you can do easily something like this:

```
declare @t as table(
[column] int
)

insert into @t
select '1001' union all
select '1002' union all
select '1003' union all
select '1004' union all
select '1005' union all
select '1006' union all
select '1007' union all
select '1008'


select
    [MyColumn1] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1001'),
    [MyColumn2] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1002'), 
    [MyColumn3] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1003'), 
    [MyColumn4] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1004') 
union all
select
    [MyColumn1] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1005'),
    [MyColumn2] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1006'), 
    [MyColumn3] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1007'), 
    [MyColumn4] = (select top 1 T.[column] from @t AS T where [T].[column] = '1008')
```

Or you could use a [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Output will be like so:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| 1001 | 1002 | 1003 | 1004 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 1005 | 1006 | 1007 | 1008 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

If it's in an exact order, you can for example do a dynamic query with a while loop, and incremeting integer variable by +1, starting at 1001. It depends.

But I bet that's not the only thing you need to select, but for your question, here is the answer :-)